# Publish database connection in server to consume from another network

Tags: database, networking

Are there have way to access private server database without creating virtual private network (VPN), as my mind I need solution like these; I able to install application each client and through it create full duplex connection between client server machine and cloud server through it database should be access anywhere else to use some specific app or public users as stream. according to the below diagram, If someone know the solution please mention.

[image]

Comment: 1) Software recommendations are off-topic 2) For networking/infrastructure questions, please see https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: actually I'm looking solution from cloud technologies, like kafka, spring cloud to achieve this problem, anyway I'll move this question to serverfault.com

Thanks

Comment: Neither of those are a database, though, and have their own networking issues to deal with if you are trying to create a sort of proxy layer

Comment: If you just want a "stream". Websockets can accomplish that; you don't need a full broker service like Kafka